# Error with combining Array types? Error: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: typescript

This code causes an error, the text of which is given below:

```
function getHandler(handlers: number[] | string[]): any {
    return handlers.map(handler => handler);
}
```

Error text:

> error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call
>   signature. Type '{ (this: [string, string, string, string, string],
>   callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, ...' has no compatible call
>   signatures.

Answer (score 6):

Change `number[] | string[]` to `(number|string)[]`

```
function getHandler(handlers: (number | string)[]): any {
    return handlers.map(handler=>handler);
}
```

Smaller repro of the issue:

```
const handlers: string[] | number[] = [];
handlers.map(x => x);
```

Reason: Simply because the type system cannot figure out from `string[]|number[]` that the item `x` might be `string|number`. The difficulty is that it is *always* either `string` or `number` and not really `string|number` simultaneously.

If you want it supported you might want to raise it here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Comment: `number[] | string[]` is not Array?